# I need to check the 'Remember me' functionality on my website. For that i need to launch IE with a already created profile using webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to  launch IE with a already created profile using webdriver?

I was able to do the same on chrome and firefox but no idea about IE. Please help me.

Comment: Does the `remember me` functionality not use cookies to actually work?

Comment: Hi Arran thanks for reply.Ya it used cookies. But i need to launch the already created profile. Do i need to check the cookie file for the same?

Comment: Can you provide more information? E.g. a code sample, error messages, ways how you tried it etc.

Comment: For chrome this code is working to launch a profile already created:
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + C:\\Users\\amit.khasa\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default);
   
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

For firefox this code is working to launch a profile already created:

ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile(data);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);

But IE niether of the above method is working

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about the concept of remember me. Just set up a cookie if the user checks remember me else set up a session in php if it is unchecked

Comment: Thanks Deval for replying. I modified my question.

Comment: can you please share some high level steps to do setup cookie concept and setup session concept. Thanks